# convert python ndarray to theano tensor type variable

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, theano

I have ndarray like :

```
diag = []
diag.append(np.diag([1,1,0]))
diag.append(np.diag([0,1,1]))
diag
  [array([[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]])]
```

How can I convert it into Theano tensor variable of type float 64, matrix ? As I need to perform dot operation like

```
Theano.dot(diag, X) where X is shared variable of type float 64, matrix.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a `SharedVariable` like this

```
diag_ = theano.shared(np.array(diag).astype("float64"))
theano.dot(diag_, X)
```

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/shared.html