# Convert numpy array into theano tensor variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, theano

I need to convert a given numpy array to theano tensor variable. I need this converted theano obj for multiplication with another theano variable.

```
def convert_fp(in_X,UpperLimit, LowerLimit):  // in_X is a numpy_array
       power = T.cast(2.**(UpperLimit - LowerLimit), theano.config.floatX)
       X = theano.shared(in_X)  // I want to the CONVERSION here
       value_tmp = X*power      // and use the converted var here
```

I am using theano 0.9.0. I tried the above code ( after looking [convert python ndarray to theano tensor type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198973/convert-python-ndarray-to-theano-tensor-type-variable) ) but its resulting in the following error:

```
"Variable type field must be a TensorType.", x, x.type)
theano.tensor.var.AsTensorError: ('Variable type field must be a TensorType.
```

I am a beginner in theano thus any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: how are you calling the function? a simple call like `convert_fp(np.array([1., 2.], 3, 2)` doesn't rise any exception for me. What exactly do you need this function for?

Comment: Same here, I can not reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong arguments were leading to the error.